# Count consecutive elements in a list

Tags: python, list, count, counter

I was doing a small program that count the number of times that a character appears in a list and I have a question, ¿Is possible to do it by consecutive numbers?.
I have this code now:

```
def function(list):
    final_list = []
    for element in set(list):
        final_list.append([element, list.count(element)])
    return final_list
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a simpler solution, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
l = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1]

[[k,len(list(v))] for k,v in groupby(l)]
# [[1, 3], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4, 2], [1, 3]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that function.